# What blogging software is used to create these websites?

Tags: php, javascript, html, blogs

What software is being used to create the following sites? I know its not e107 so dont get confused from the favicon.

- http://www.selfdiploma.com/blog
- http://www.iguitarmag.com/blog

I have no clue what the blog software is called but if someone can tell me and point me in the correct direction i would appreciate it.

Comment: When you contacted the site administrators, what did they say?

Comment: "I never contacted them".  That's a solvable problem.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the HTML source (specifically, some of the javascript), it looks like both sites were created using [Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com/).

Comment: it looks as if it is spquare space!@ thanks!